# How to parse attribute in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: json.net

We have following JSON output from an API.

We are using the following code in ASP.NET to deserialize a JSON response to a class:

```
var j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<classname>(response);
```

While deserializing the following JSON, we are unable to get the attribute values.

```
{
    "User": {
        "Address": {
            "@CityName": "Test",
            "$": "B4C99EB0-18E6-439F-882A-9E4A11E1FF75"
        }
    }
}
```

As per the above example we need to get `@cityname` and `$` attribute values.

We need following output in the class:

```
@CityName : Test
$ : B4C99EB0-18E6-439F-882A-9E4A11E1FF75
```

I am getting the element value, but I am not able to get the attribute values.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `[JsonProperty]` attribute to map non-standard JSON property names to properties in your class.  Make your classes like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [JsonProperty("@CityName")]
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("$")]
    public string Guid { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize like this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
```